# How can I see state within a function? using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update the uploadFiles state inside my updateFile function, when reloading the file, I'm rewriting this component in hooks, but inside the function the state is given as empty.

```js
  const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState({
    slides: [],
    material: [],
  });

  const updateFile = useCallback(
    (id, data) => {
      const value = uploadedFiles.slides.map(uploadedFile => {
        return id === uploadedFile.id
          ? { ...uploadedFile, ...data }
          : uploadedFile;
      });

      console.log('value', value);
      console.log('uploadedFilesOnFunction', uploadedFiles);
    },
    [uploadedFiles]
  );

  function processUpload(upFile, type) {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('file', upFile.file, upFile.name);

    api
      .post('dropbox', data, {
        onUploadProgress: e => {
          const progress = parseInt(Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total), 10);

          updateFile(upFile.id, {
            progress,
          });
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        updateFile(upFile.id, {
          uploaded: true,
          id: response.data.id,
          url: response.data.url,
          type,
        });
      })
      .catch(response => {
        updateFile(upFile.id, {
          error: true,
        });
      });
  }

  function handleUpload(files, type) {
    const uploaded = files.map(file => ({
      file,
      id: uniqueId(),
      name: file.name,
      readableSize: filesize(file.size),
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      progress: 0,
      uploaded: false,
      error: false,
      url: null,
      type,
    }));
    setUploadedFiles({
      slides: uploadedFiles.slides.concat(uploaded),
    });
    uploaded.forEach(e => processUpload(e, type));
  }

  console.log('slides', uploadedFiles);
```

I expected the state values to be viewed by the function. For me to manipulate and set the state.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other issues, but one thing I've noticed is:

```
const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState({
  slides: [],
  material: [],
});

// A setState CALL FROM THE useState HOOK REPLACES THE STATE WITH THE NEW VALUE

setUploadedFiles({
  slides: uploadedFiles.slides.concat(uploaded),
});
```

**From:** https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

> State variables can hold objects and arrays just fine, so you can still group related data together. However, unlike this.setState in a class, **updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.**

The `setState` from the `useState` hook doesn't merge the state. Because it can hold any type of value, not only objects, like we used to do with classes.

From your code you can see that you're erasing some property from state when you're updating like that.

Instead, you should use the functional form of the `setState` and access the current state `prevState`, like:

```
setUploadedFiles((prevState) => {
  return({
    ...prevState,
    slides: uploadedFiles.slides.concat(uploaded)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated updateFiles function:

```js
 const updateFile = (id, data) => {
    setUploadedFiles(prevState => {
      const newSlide = prevState.slides.map(slide => {
        return id === slide.id ? { ...slide, ...data } : slide;
      });

      return {
        ...prevState,
        slides: newSlide,
      };
    });
  };
```